# multiple variable reassignment when importing

Tags: python, import

I can't seem to find this answer on Google. I'm unable to import and reassign multiple modules/variables in a single line.

```
from A import B as C  # works fine
from A import Y as Z  # works fine

from A import B,Y as C,Z  # does not work
```

Even trying with `builtin` modules this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> import sys,requests as SYS,REQUESTS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'REQUESTS'
```

Do I have to keep import reassignments on separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

`from A import B as C, Y as Z`

should work i think

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from A import B as C, Y as Z
```